# Unable to put a png image on the border edge of a container

Tags: html, css, fonts

Not sure why I am unable to butt the .png image to the border of the container.  I have tried everything.  Padding, margin, position, and the image does not move down. I even tried moving the image out of the container but that would add too much extra work and script.  I am hoping someone can help me here.  I was unable to load the code.  It's a document with HTML and CSS.  The image is a class within a div.  Any help would be wonderful. I am unable to load the image as well.

file:///Users/suzannehunter/Desktop/web%20development/CSS-My%20Site/index.html

Comment: The only way we might help is to see your relevant “*[mcve]*” code, are you able to share that with us?

Comment: Hmmm are you sure that with the css you are having an effect in the image?? Then are you sure that the div that is inside don't have padding?? If you could post the code it would be better.

Comment: Giving us a path to a file on your local machine isn't going to do us any good. Please use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to add a runnable snippet of your code to your question. You'll need to provide the image as a data URI or as a fully qualified URL to an internet-accessible location.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses.  I was able to figure out how to add the code...I hope...This is my first post..

Answer (score 0):

Give your parent div `position relative` and the child `position absolute`. Then you specify on with side the image is going to overlap the border. if the left side use `left: -5px(the negative value of the border thickness)`, or right: for the right side.

```
<div style="background:red;border:5px solid black;position: relative;height: 200px;width: 100px;">
        <div style="background: blue;height: 50px;width: 50px;position: absolute;right: -5px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your response, I tried changing the position's like you stated.  The Parent was already (top container) was already relative.  When I changed the child (img of boxer) absolute it stays fixed and doesn't float with the rest of the children within the Parent.  Do I add Float? Placement is another matter. I will try once again to include the code.  Wouldn't let me add the code and the image last time. How do you add the code or won't they allow it?[

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AnimalKrate</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=EB+Garamond&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-container">
      <img class="top-bone" src="images/bone.png" alt="bone-img">
      <h1>AnimalKrate</h1>
        <h2><span class="pet">PET</span> source for everything</h2>
        <img class="bottom-bone" src="images/bone.png" alt="bone">
        <img  class="boxer" src="images/boxer.png" alt="boxer-img">
  </div>
 <div class="middle-container">
      <div class="profile">
        <img src="images/pawprint.png" alt="pawprint" style = "padding-top:25px">
        <h2 style="margin-bottom:5px;">Woof</h2>
        <p class="intro">We are your source for everything a pet lover loves. Buying and selling only the most sought after specialty items.</p>
      </div>

      <hr>
      <div class="skills">
        <h2>Pet Toys</h2>
        <div class="skill-row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
          <img class="dog-ball" src="images/dog-ball.png" alt="dog-ball">

          <h3>Lorem & Ipsum</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis in duis, iaculis id felis. Consectetuer vestibulum, nunc urna lectus, erat ligula. Hendrerit nam, lectus ante, ut lorem eros.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="skill-row" style= "margin-bottom: 50px;">
          <img class="dog-toy" src="images/dog-toy.png" alt="dog-toy">
          <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, mauris sed consectetuer. Etiam et eu, bibendum interdum, lacus quis mauris. Curabitur wisi, quisque vel eu, rutrum nam.</p>
        </div>
  </div>
      <hr>


     </div>

    <div class="bottom-container">
      <div class="contact-me">
        <h2 style = "padding-top: 25px;">Get In Touch</h2>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, non elit.</h3>
        <p class="contact-message">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in quis, aenean amet. Phasellus sodales, tellus donec dui, ornare erat.</p>
        <a class="myButton">Contact Me</a>
        <a href="mailto:2Turkeywithlove.com"></a>
      </div>
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.chewy.com/">Chewy</a>
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.krisers.com/">Krisers</a>
      <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.petsmart.com/">Petsmart</a>
      <p class="copyright">© 2018 Hunter.</p>

    </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOaTO.png)

```css
body{
  color: #405143;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
  font-size: 18px;

}

h1{
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  font-family:'Fredoka One', cursive;

}

h2 {
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 25px;



}

h3 {
   color:#794646;
   font-family: 'open sans condensed';
   font-weight:bolder;



}

a{

  color: #794646;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
     color: #5b5b5b;

}
p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #d8c292;
  position:relative;
  padding-top: 20px;


}

.middle-container{


}

.bottom-container{
  background-color: #c19065;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 25px;

}

.pet {

  text-decoration: underline;
}

.bottom-bone{

  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  bottom: 300px;

}

.top-bone{
   position: absolute;
   right: 200px;
   top: 150px;


}

.contact-message {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto 30px;
}

.copyright{

     font-size: 1rem;
     padding:20px 0px;

}
.skill-row{
      width: 50%;
      margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
      text-align: left;

}

.intro {
   width:30%;
   margin: auto;

}

.pawprint {
   width: 25%;


}

.dog-ball {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;

}

.dog-toy {
  width: 35%;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;


}

hr{
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width:5px;
  width: 5%;

}

.style {

   margin-top:30px;
}

.boxer{

  
}

.myButton {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    background-color:#eae0c2;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #333029;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#505739;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:9px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
  }
  .myButton:hover {
    background-color:#ccc2a6;
  }
  .myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;

  }
```

```html
body{
  color: #405143;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
  font-size: 18px;

}

h1{
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  font-family:'Fredoka One', cursive;

}

h2 {
  color: #5b5b5b;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-top: 25px;



}

h3 {
   color:#794646;
   font-family: 'open sans condensed';
   font-weight:bolder;



}

a{

  color: #794646;
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover{
     color: #5b5b5b;

}
p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #d8c292;
  position:relative;
  padding-top: 20px;


}

.middle-container{


}

.bottom-container{
  background-color: #c19065;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 25px;

}

.pet {

  text-decoration: underline;
}

.bottom-bone{

  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
  bottom: 300px;

}

.top-bone{
   position: absolute;
   right: 200px;
   top: 150px;


}

.contact-message {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 20px auto 30px;
}

.copyright{

     font-size: 1rem;
     padding:20px 0px;

}
.skill-row{
      width: 50%;
      margin: 100px auto 100px auto;
      text-align: left;

}

.intro {
   width:30%;
   margin: auto;

}

.pawprint {
   width: 25%;


}

.dog-ball {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;

}

.dog-toy {
  width: 35%;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;


}

hr{
  margin-top:40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width:5px;
  width: 5%;

}

.style {

   margin-top:30px;
}

.boxer{

  
}

.myButton {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    background-color:#eae0c2;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #333029;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#505739;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:9px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffffff;
  }
  .myButton:hover {
    background-color:#ccc2a6;
  }
  .myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;

  }
```